# Converting argument to partial string

Tags: r

I'm sure this is pretty basic, but I haven't been able to find an answer on stackoverflow.

The basics of what I'm working with is

```
f1 <- function(x) {
setwd("~/Rdir/x")
col1 <- f2(...)
col2 <- f3(...)
genelist <- data.frame(co1,col2)
write.csv(genelist, file="x.csv")
}
```

Essentially what I want is for x to be replaced by whatever I input for example
`f1(test)` would save a file called test.csv into the directory Rdir/test.

I would post a more complete code sample of what i'm working with - but it is very long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `?paste`:

```
setwd(paste("~/Rdir/", x, sep=""));
```

and

```
write.csv(genelist, file=paste(x, ".csv", sep=""))
```

in your example. However, it might me more straightforward not to change the working directory but instead just to specify the full path when saving:

```
write.csv(genelist, file=paste("~/Rdir/", x, "/", x, ".csv", sep=""))
```

but be aware that this will crash if the directory does not exist. You could have a look at `?dir.create` to create the directory first, in case it does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for this, very simple yet very effective.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the filename with `paste0` and the path with `file.path`:

```
x <- "test"
file.path("~/Rdir", x, paste0(x, ".csv"))
# "~/Rdir/test/test.csv"
```